# Where do I put IPython configuration files?

Tags: python, emacs, editor, ipython

I have been trying to set my %edit editor to Emacs for a while and made very slow progress.

The IPython 0.13 docs were unclear about how to actually configure this. It told me to set EDITOR to the desired editor (in my case, "emacsclient") by adding

```
c = get_config()
c.InteractiveShell.editor = 'emacsclient'
```

to my config in my ipython folder.

However, I couldn't find any such folder. I spent a very long time looking around to find just how to set IPython environment variables and found only related snippets. What code to use. The difference between .py and .ipy files for startup scripts. Etc.

I am using Ubuntu 12.10. Where do I put my config file for IPython 0.13?

Comment: Changed title from "how can I change IPython's default editor" after I realized that's not what I'm asking. Hope that's right.

Comment: I actually have an answer for this, but can't post it due to low rep.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I have `c.TerminalInteractiveShell.editor = 'emacsclient'` in `~/.config/ipython/profile_default/ipython_config.py` and it works.

If you have trouble finding config location, use `ipython locate profile` command:
http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/rel-0.13/whatsnew/version0.13.html#new-top-level-locate-command

But I think the easiest way to setup editor is to have something like `export EDITOR=emacsclient` in your *shell* setup (e.g. `~/.bashrc`).

Comment: Very nice. Since I'd gotten it working as I said above, I ininstalled and purged everything, deleted ~/.config/ipython, reinstalled, and followed your directions, and my problems from last time disappeared. Don't even remember what I did before now. Also did NOT realize it was actually drawing on the shell environment's editor. Tried that out separately, and it works great as well, though not for qtconsole mode. I'll just edit that part into your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Per the [docs](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/intro.html), run `ipython profile create` and it will make a file for you with all the options (commented out) and tell you where it is. By default, it's at `~/.ipython/profile_default/ipython_config.py`.