# How to set up vim to work with Ipython %edit magic function in QTconsole (Mac)?

Tags: python, vim, ipython, qtconsole

`%edit` works in terminal, but in qtconsole I get a message that the default editor is not set in IPythonWidget.editor. Where can I find this file? Google suggest modifying `ipython_config`, but I found like 10 files with that name on my laptop.

I forgot to mention that my goal is to launch vim inside the console.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15409096/2677943) might help you with finding the config. Basically just see what `ipython locate profile` prints.

Comment: Well I figured out that I did not have a default profile to begin with. So I created it using 'ipython profile create' command. Anyway, when I add 'vim' in the qtconsole and ipython_confing files, nothing changes.